# dplyr mutate_at: create new variables with recode

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I can't create multiple reversed variables with dplyr.

Definition of the problem:

```
df <- data.frame (V1 =c (1,2,2,1,2), V2 = c(2,2,1,2,2), V3 = c(3,5,2,1,4))
```

I want to invert values 1 and 2 in the first 2 variables.
I've tried many things, but nothing works.

I want to obtain

```
V1  V2  V3
2   1   3
1   1   5
1   2   2
2   1   1
1   1   4
```

Comment: thanks. I'm looking to use mutate_at. Any solution?

Comment: `df %>%  mutate_at(vars(V1:V2), ~if_else(. == 1, 2, 1))`

Comment: Is this just `new <- 3 - old`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways to attack this. A simple `case_when` statement would suffice:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  V1 =c (1,2,2,1,2), 
  V2 = c(2,2,1,2,2), 
  V3 = c(3,5,2,1,4)
)
df
#>   V1 V2 V3
#> 1  1  2  3
#> 2  2  2  5
#> 3  2  1  2
#> 4  1  2  1
#> 5  2  2  4

df %>%
  mutate(
    V1 = case_when(V1 == 1 ~ 2, V1 == 2 ~ 1),
    V2 = case_when(V2 == 1 ~ 2, V2 == 2 ~ 1)
  )
#>   V1 V2 V3
#> 1  2  1  3
#> 2  1  1  5
#> 3  1  2  2
#> 4  2  1  1
#> 5  1  1  4
```

But since you said `mutate_at`, you probably want to use a function:

```r
flip_ones_and_twos <- function(x) {
  return(x %% 2 + 1)
}

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(V1, V2), ~ flip_ones_and_twos(.))
#>   V1 V2 V3
#> 1  2  1  3
#> 2  1  1  5
#> 3  1  2  2
#> 4  2  1  1
#> 5  1  1  4
```

I'm certain there are other approaches as well (e.g. `if.else` or `if_else`).

Comment: Doesn't make a huge difference, but you can just pass that function as `mutate_at(vars(V1, V2), flip_ones_and_twos)` without the formula notation